# How has the current governmental funding affected NSF GRFP?

Tags: graduate-school, funding, nsf

As I was reading about the NSF GRFP, I came across [this article](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/05/how-nsf-cut-11-its-budget) detailing how the GRFP would be significantly defunded as per the governmental budget at the time.

I'm sure the landscape has changed since May. However, I haven't seen any followup articles. I also notice that within the solicitation for the GRFP, it states the following:
"The NSF expects to award 2,000 Graduate Research Fellowships per fiscal year under this program solicitation pending availability of
funds."

However, I am not aware of a way to check the funding for these awards. Can anyone confirm that the number of GRFP awards will be halved this coming cycle?

Answer (score 1):

There is no final decision yet, but the following commentary from the American Institute of Physics suggests that [there might not be major changes to the size of the program](https://www.aip.org/fyi/2017/fy18-appropriations-bills-national-science-foundation):

> Of particular note, the Senate report does not accept the administration’s request to reduce funding for the Graduate Research Fellowship Program (GRFP), and “instead provides the fiscal year 2017 funding level” for the program. The administration has requested to halve the number of new participants to 1,000. It is unclear if the Senate directive applies to GRFP funding allocated through the research directorates or just EHR funds.

It is worth noting that these changes would apply to the *next* cycle, not the current one.